# How to do a "PHP" regex in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

sorry for the specific question but I'm looking for a way to convert his PHP regex :

```
    preg_match_all('#value="(.*)" name="MYNAME"#U', $content, $return);
```

Into C#

I know how to use C# functions to search & match for the regex but my problem is more with the regular expressions itself, I don't know how to "translate" it into C# format

thanks a lot !!

Comment: The only thing in that regular expression that doesn't translate verbatim are the delimiters and the `U` option. Have you looked for an example of an ungreedy C# regex?

Answer (score 3):

The only "weird" thing you can describe for the regular expression is the `U` (ungreedy) flag, also as [zneak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251153/zneak) pointed in his comment. If you want to use the same behavior you can use a regex like this:

```
value="(.*?)" name="MYNAME"
          ^--- Ungreedy or lazy modifier
```

Update: as **[Lucas Trzesniewski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3764814/lucas-trzesniewski)** pointed in his comment:

> and since you have double quotes inside the regex, you'd best escape them like that:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"value=""(.*?)"" name=""MYNAME""");
```

Comment: ... and since you have double quotes inside the regex, you'd best escape them like that: `var regex = new Regex(@"value=""(.*?)"" name=""MYNAME""");` (and to use *any* PHP regex in C# see my profile)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski thanks for the useful comment. Updated.